# ldd says library isn't found by compile completes successfully

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I am attempting to compile project. It compiles successfully. My `make` command exits with a status code of `0` and there are no errors displayed.

However, the project is not working, and when I run `ldd -d <file>` it shows that I have two libraries that are not found.

```
>ldd -d output_file.so
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77e0000)
    libvstdlib_srv.so => not found
    libtier0_srv.so => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7760000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf775b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf75a9000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x46e4a000)
undefined symbol: pfVectorNormalize     (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: _Z12VectorAnglesRK6VectorR6QAngle     (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: pfSqrt       (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: __cxa_guard_acquire   (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: __cxa_guard_release   (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: _Z6ConMsgPKcz (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: Warning      (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: __dynamic_cast        (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: _Z11ConColorMsgRK5ColorPKcz   (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: Error (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: AssertValidStringPtr  (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: _AssertValidWritePtr  (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: _AssertValidReadPtr   (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE     (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE      (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE (output_file.so)
undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0  (output_file.so)
```

These two libraries are set up as symbolic links to the actual location of the file:

```
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Andy Andy    62 May  2 12:30 libtier0_srv.so -> /home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/lib/linux/libtier0_srv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Andy Andy    64 May  2 12:30 libvstdlib_srv.so -> /home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/lib/linux/libvstdlib_srv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 Andy Andy  5444 May  2 11:53 Makefile
...
```

The `gcc` command being run is

`gcc -I/home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/public/game/server -I. -I.. -ICEntity -Isdk -I/home/dev/project1/hl2sdk-ob-valve/public -I/home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/public/engine -I/home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/public/tier0 -I/home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/public/tier1 -I/home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/public/mathlib -I/home/dev/project1/mmsource-central/core -I/home/dev/project1/mmsource-central/core/sourcehook -I/home/dev/project1/sourcemod-central/public -I/home/dev/project1/sourcemod-central/public/sourcepawn -I/home/dev/project1/sourcemod-central/core project1_output/sdk/smsdk_ext.o project1_output/extension.o project1_output/CTrackingProjectile.o project1_output/CSentryRocket.o project1_output/CProjectileRocket.o project1_output/CProjectileArrow.o project1_output/CProjectileFlare.o project1_output/CProjectilePipe.o project1_output/CProjectileSyringe.o project1_output/CEntity/CEntity.o project1_output/CEntity/CEntityManager.o project1_output/CEntity/CPlayer.o /home/dev/project1/hl2sdk-ob-valve/lib/linux/tier1_i486.a libvstdlib_srv.so libtier0_srv.so -m32 -lm -ldl -static-libgcc -shared -o project1_output/output_file.so`

My questions are:
1.) Why are those two libraries not found even though they are symlinked?
2.) The undefined symbols are part of the `mathlib` package, which is included in the `gcc` command. `-I/home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/public/mathlib` Why would these be undefined, despite being included?

`c++` is not my language of choice and I know enough about Makefiles to be dangerous, but not really to fix anything, so I apologize if this is not enough information. I can provide more as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library files are shared objects, which means that they will not be resolved until run time. In order for ldd to find them (assuming Linux or other Unix variant) you will need to add the path the libraries to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH (there is another path env that can be used but I can't think of it right now) and then ldd should be able to find the library.

Answer (score 15):

I just stumbled upon this, had the same problem but a different solution.

Using LD_LIBRARY_PATH will, in fact work. And it is fine if it is for your own testing in your build environment, but you should try to avoid it besides for a case like this. Here is an article by someone who knows much more than me about it, why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is bad:

http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html

What happened is, as can be seen also from the fact that setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH worked, is that at runtime, your program could not find the shared library `libtier0_srv.so`. Instead of globally setting a variable for all programs to look at `/home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/lib/linux/` first, you should add the directory to the runtime library search path. You do this by passing the option

`-rpath /home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/lib/linux/`

to `ld`, the linker. You can do this with your `gcc` command you posted, by adding the option

`-Wl,-rpath,/home/dev/sdks/hl2sdk-ob-valve/lib/linux/`,

which tells `gcc` to pass the option above to `ld`.

Comment: Yes, this is better than the 'sledgehammer' approach of setting an environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

As @diverscuba23 mentioned, you need to add the path your library is located at to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  An easy, and non permanent way of doing this is specifying it when you run the program like so:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./yourProgram
```

In this case the library would need to be within the same directory you are running the program.

More generally:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<PATH_TO_YOUR_LIBRARY>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./yourProgram
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output file is *.so, a shared object library file; symbols from another shared library are referenced but not imported (static link).
-- use nm to view the symbols (defined or undefined)

ldd will search the ldconfig system cache and /etc/ld.so.conf informs where to search
-- you can use this feature to add library paths (example: /opt/valve/lib) to share with all users

-- Your compile command includes shared library archives from your home directory.

---- ldd will not normally search home directories, use LD_LIBRARY_PATH

------ but you must list the full path to the directory

you said you 'included' mathlib, I see this was as -I (for header files)

-- but library directories are -L $MY_PATH/mathlib/lib and -l vstdlib_srv links it

----you included the library rather than linking it
-- in C/C++ the meaning of include is different then other languages: use/require/import/include

---- this declares symbols, types and param lists; but not the implementation

-I provides the path for *.h, *.hh, *.hpp; which are text files to declare symbols

-L provides the path to find libraries (and static libs to link the exec)

-l links a library containing the implementation

-rpath provides the runtime path for the libs to link to the exec and compile it into the exec

---- this binds the application and its library location (example -rpath ../lib, when the app is in bin)